# Return value outside of loop when it was initial inside of loop

Tags: java

I tried return answer[] outside of the loop, but it only works when it was initialized before the loop. I am confused now, is that because it has to be declared before the loop to avoid it become the local variable?
this is my code(if int[] inside of if-condition, it would not return)

```
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int[] answer = new int[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length-1; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < nums.length; j++) {
                if(nums[i]+nums[j] == target){
                    //int[] answer = new int[2];
                    answer[0] = i;
                    answer[1] = j;
                }
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Comment: First decide on answers to these two questions: 1) What should be returned if the `if` statement is never true? 2) What should be returned if the `if` statement is true more than once?

Answer (score 0):

The local may never get executed within the loop. Even without the `if`, the loops may execute zero times.

Furthermore, the rules for *definite assignment* are quite long - check the JLS. Any further complications would not be welcome.

If `answer` was a field, then it would be implicitly initialised to `null` and may, therefore, cause `NullPointerException`s unless you are careful.

Comment: throw new IllegalArgumentException("ERROR"); If I add this in the end. Will it help?

Comment: You need to definitely exit as there is a return value. So yeah, if you put the return inside (to return on first match instead of last) then throwing an exception at the end should work.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to define what the answers to these two questions are:

1. What should be returned if the `if` statement is never true?
2. What should be returned if the `if` statement is true more than once?

Assuming the answer to the first is "null", and the answer to the second is "first match", then you'd write the code like this:

```
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                return new int[] { i, j }; // returning first match immediately
            }
        }
    }
    return null; // answer to first question here
}
```

Comment: @xyz666999 Welcome to StackOverflow. You should click the up-arrow of any/all answers you find useful. If your question has been answered to your satisfaction, click the check mark next to the best answer to *accept* it, so other than see that the question has been resolved.